# How to replace text in runtime in PIXI.Text object

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

im using PIXIJS to create a game. i want a status message to be replaced when some events occur. The problem is that the text added above but the old text is not removed :

This sounds a very simple task, but i didnt find any method to change text in the documentation for Pixt.Text object.
Thanks .

```
var statusMessage;
// create a Text Sprite from a text message
function getStausMessageSprite(message){
    var style = {font: 'bold italic 36px Arial'};
    var statusMessage = new PIXI.Text(message.value, style);
    statusMessage.x = 10;
    statusMessage.y = 550;
    return statusMessage;
}

// drawing status message (update message)
function drawStatusMessage(message) {
    // try to remove the old sprite from the stage (it still appears)
    app.stage.removeChild(statusMessage);
    // create a new Text Sprite and add it 
    statusMessage = getStausMessageSprite(message);
    app.stage.addChild(statusMessage);
}
```

Comment: Just change the `statusMessage.text` property, here are the docs: http://pixijs.download/release/docs/PIXI.Text.html#text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As HankMoody says in his comment: change the .text property. You don't need to make a new object.

```
function updateStatusMessage(message) {
    statusMessage.text = message.value;
}
```

Also, the reason why your example doesn't correctly remove the text is probably this:

You declare a global `var statusMessage;` and then declare it again in the `getStausMessageSprite` function. I'm guessing the global `statusMessage` won't contain the new text object.

Remove the 2nd var and it will probably work:

```
// create a Text Sprite from a text message
function getStausMessageSprite(message){
    var style = {font: 'bold italic 36px Arial'};
    statusMessage = new PIXI.Text(message.value, style);
    statusMessage.x = 10;
    statusMessage.y = 550;
    return statusMessage;
}
```

Final note: I have learned recently, if you use `let` instead of `var`, it won't let you redeclare a variable and gives an error instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var textObj = new PIXI.Text('sample', {
  fontFamily: 'Rokkitt',
  fontStyle: 'normal',
  fontWeight: '600',
  fontSize: 32,
  fill: '#F5F5F5'
});textObj.text = "update val"
```

we can replace text on runtime using **textObj.text**.